# PhoneGap(3.4.0) android app with sqlite, its working fine in emulator but not in device

Tags: android, cordova

I have created in PhoneGap(3.4.0) android app with sqlite, its working fine in emulator ***but not working in device***. I am using populated database with lots of records. I have googled to much, but not solved my issue. **Error is**:

```
SQLitePlugin.executeSql[Batch](): Error=no such table: my_table_name (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * from my_table_name
```

**My code:**

```
db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("myDB.sqlite", "1.0", "DB", 4000000);
db.transaction(function(tx) {      
     tx.executeSql("SELECT * from my_table_name", [], function(tx, res)  {                                           
      });
});
```

Comment: i have done already .

Comment: hmmm seems like `no such table` ... that's it, problem solved ... Off-topic on SO: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.` this code will generate such error as there is no `CREATE TABLE` statment ...

Comment: hehe `I dont want to creat` - then you will not have ... simple logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue using this, If you are working for emulator then copy your databas using command prompt, I have added myDB.sqlite in asset folder then run

**adb push myDB.sqlite /data/data/com.my_app.my_app/databases/myDB.sqlite**

For device, just put them in to bundle of app that is assets folder in case of Android . you need myDB.sqlite and file__0/0000000000000001.sqlite files. ***[More....](http://gauravstomar.blogspot.ca/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html)***

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   super.init();
   try
   {
        String pName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
        this.copy("myDB.sqlite","/data/data/"+pName+"/databases/");
        this.copy("0000000000000001.sqlite","/data/data/"+pName+"/app_database/file__0/");
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

  super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());    
}

void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException 
{

   File CheckDirectory;
   CheckDirectory = new File(folder);
   if (!CheckDirectory.exists())
   { 
     CheckDirectory.mkdir();
   }

   InputStream in = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(file);
   OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder+file);
   // Transfer bytes from in to out
   byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
   int len; while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) out.write(buf, 0, len);
   in.close(); out.close();

}
```

## For iOS you can use following steps:

**Step 1 :** Remove the **.sqlite** extension from the **sqlite** database. Ex. If we have the database called **myDB.sqlite** make it only **myDB**.

**Step 2 :** Then drag the **myDB** file to Resource directory in Xcode by choosing the option “Create groups for any added folder” and check the “Copy items into destination group’s folder (if needed)” option while adding reference.

**Step 3 :** Now use the following code to copy the database into the Document directory inside our application.

```
-(void) copyDatabase{

   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
   NSError *error;

   NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
   BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

   if(!success) {

     NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDB"];
     success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

     if (!success)
       NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
  }
 }

- (NSString *) getDBPath
{

   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDB"];
}
```

**Step 4 :** Use this code **[self copyDatabase];** and call this in the **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions(AppDelegate.m )** method like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
   [self copyDatabase];
}
```

Now open the database using following code.

```
function openDatabase() {
      try{
           if(!!window.openDatabase){
            var openDB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name : "myDB"});
           }else{
              navigator.notification.alert("Local database is not supported by your device.");
           }
      }
      catch(error){
         console.log("ERROR:" + error.message);
 }
```

***[More detail...](http://mindfiremobile.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/copy-existing-sqlite-database-into-phonegap-ios-application/)***