# How to store data permanently in Cordova using Sqlite

Tags: android, database, html, sqlite, cordova

I am for the first time using Cordova Phonegap application for Android Platform .For Storing of small data into my phone device i am using sqlite database.At this stage i am able to create database,table and perform `CRUD` operation .Till now everything is all right.The main issue that i am facing right now is that the database that i have created is not permanent .I tried everything thinking it will be stored as permanent into the mobile device but once `app` closes every thing vanishes ..
Here is the code that i am trying ..

```
var databaseName =  "techDB";
var databaseVersion = "1.0";
var databaseDisplayName = "ttDatabase";
var databaseSize =  10000;      

myDB = window.openDatabase(databaseName, databaseVersion , databaseDisplayName, databaseSize);
```

After this i am trying all `CRUD` operations..
Please help me to save the data permanent into my cordova android application..
Thanks..

Comment: See this post, it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187826/websql-for-phonegap-application/27189861#27189861

Answer (score 0):

Hello why not use WebSql database to store your data, event though its depreciated (ie. not anymore supported by W3C) it is still used by many. Here is a link hope it helps

http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/