# How to access data from SQLite databse and display in HTML page in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Hi I am new on `PhoneGap`. I have created a SQLite database using `CordovaPlugin`.

Now I want to fetch all data using method from that SQLite class and want to display in HTML page.

How can I achieve it.

Please help me.

Comment: See link it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187826/websql-for-phonegap-application/27189861#27189861

Answer (score 0):

Download the code from https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin and install it in your project.

Update the config.xml file.

Reference the plugin in your html head area.

I have full working steps here, which includes the deviceready script and full database code with sample data: http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/installing-chris-brodys-sqlite-database-with-cordova-cli-android/