# Cordova Android SQLLIteplugin.open exception

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I am trying to use SQLLItePlugin for Android but its not working. I will list my steps:
1. I have installed cordova pjhonegap from phonegap. I am developing my mobile app Phonegap, html5, javascript, css3 using Netbeans as IDE.
2. Downloaded plugin from https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin.
3. Added SQLitePlugin.js to js folder of project.
4. Added com.brodysoft.sqlitePlugin.file=https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin.git in plugin.properties.
5. Am opening database on deviceready as

```
       var app = {
   initialize: function () {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function () {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase('gdata.db');
        console.log('ready');


         db.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table');
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (id integer primary key, data text, data_num integer)');

                // demonstrate PRAGMA:
                db.executeSql("pragma table_info (test_table);", [], function (res) {
                    console.log("PRAGMA res: " + JSON.stringify(res));
                });

                tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)", ["test", 100], function (tx, res) {
                    console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- probably 1");
                    console.log("rowsAffected: " + res.rowsAffected + " -- should be 1");

                    db.transaction(function (tx) {
                        tx.executeSql("select count(id) as cnt from test_table;", [], function (tx, res) {
                            console.log("res.rows.length: " + res.rows.length + " -- should be 1");
                            console.log("res.rows.item(0).cnt: " + res.rows.item(0).cnt + " -- should be 1");
                        });
                    });

                }, function (e) {
                    console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
                });
        });



    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function (id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
app.initialize();
```

6. Running the build on android devvice directly.

It keeps on throwing the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'exec'
>   (13:52:13:450 | error, javascript)
>       at SQLitePlugin.open (www/js/libs/SQLitePlugin.js:112:15)
>       at SQLitePlugin (www/js/libs/SQLitePlugin.js:54:10)
>       at (anonymous function) (www/js/libs/SQLitePlugin.js:425:14)
>       at (anonymous function) (www/js/libs/SQLitePlugin.js:30:20)
>       at createandpopulatedb (www/js/dborarray.js:30:30)
>       at onDeviceReady3 (www/dborarray.html:96:33)
>       at onload (www/dborarray.html:16:155) SQLitePlugin openargs: {"name":"gdata`enter code here`.db"} (13:52:19:609)   at
>   www/js/libs/SQLitePlugin.js:39

Can somebody help.

Comment: Follow this link it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187826/websql-for-phonegap-application/27189861#27189861

Answer (score 1):

try thhis

```
window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "gdata.db"});
```

instead of this

```
window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase('gdata.db');
```