# Access sqlite database from assets in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i have a question about phonegap with sqlite database.I have prepopulated database in my assets folder "myDB.db" and my problem is i want to access database direct from assets folder into phonegap. I don't want to copy into sd card or don't use external database. 
  Regards

Comment: are you using DBHelper class?

Comment: Prepopulate SQLite DataBase in PhoneGap Application :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187826/websql-for-phonegap-application/27189861#27189861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this is in your code

```
        //Please place your db file in wwww directory ,here example : projectpath/www/santosh.db
            db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "santosh.db", createFromLocation: 1});
```

and for more reference follow the steps on following link...

http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2015/03/open-existing-sqlite-file-in-phonegap.html

Hopes it may help you.